# Radius of Convergence of Power Series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\tanh^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

What is the radius of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\tanh^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$? Justify your answer.

---

*My steps toward a solution*

I can express $\tanh$ simpler as:
\begin{align*}
\tanh z
&=\frac{\sinh z}{\cosh z} \\
&=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}
\end{align*}
However I'm not sure what the $n^{th}$ derivative of this would be.

I also know [Cauchy's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), which says for a Jordan curve $J$ and holomorphic function $f$ on $J \cup Int(J)$, we can compute for any $a \in Int(J)$
\begin{equation}
f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_J \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\, dz
\end{equation}
but I'm not sure how to apply that.

I also have some other formulas,
\begin{equation}
f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a-a_0\right)^n \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_J \frac{f(z)}{\left(z-a_0\right)^{n+1}}\, dz
\end{equation}
for $|a-a_0|< dist(a_0,J)$
and
\begin{equation}
f^{(n)}\left(a_0\right)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \oint_J \frac{f(z)}{\left(z-a_0\right)^{n+1}}\, dz
\end{equation}
for $a_0 \in Int(J)$.

However, I'm not sure how I would apply these formulas either (if that's actually what I'm supposed to do!). Thanks for helping me understand this and work this out.

Comment: Why can't you use the ratio test?

Comment: Here is my professor's hint: "Since $\tanh$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}$ is a real analytic function, one may ask this question with only Real Analysis. However, it is hard to answer without Complex Analysis."

Comment: By real analysis I would assume he means ratio test or root test then.

Comment: How we use the ratio test & what we get?

Comment: I think, it is sufficient to test that where the function $f(z)=\tanh z$ is analytic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radius of convergence is the distance of $0$ to the closest singularity of $\tanh z$. The singularities of $\tanh z$ are the zeroes of $\cosh z$. These are
$$
\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\,i+2\,k\,\pi\,i,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
The radius of convergence is thus $\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems simple, to make sure the denominator ($\cosh$) is not equal to zero. But is there more to prove? How can we be sure that the power series converges for the other $z$ inside the radius and not any of those $z$ outside the radius?

Comment: $\tanh z$ is holomorphic in $\{|z|<\pi/2\}$. It follows from Cauchy's formula that it is equal to its Taylor series on that domain.